# TortoiseSVN lost local changes after SVN Update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I did an SVN Update, and I ended up with a file in conflicted status and some merges.  But for two of my files, it completely removed my version of the files and replaced them with the version in the repository.  There are no *.mine files or anything like that.  I remember seeing a message about restoring 2 files, which were the ones I lost my changes on.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For conflicted files :

   ```
   Open it in difference/compare window or notepad & see the >>>>mine and 
   >>>>revision markers in your code. Keep the necesaary one and remove the other 
   along with the markers >>>>>mine and >>>>>>revision. Now right click on your 
   file ,tortiosesvn-> Resolved Conflicts and click ok and checkin the file. 
   Your fileis now update,merged and also committed to svn without any conflict.
   ```
2. For lost changes - `Right click on the file Show Log -> See the last revision and get it.`

**I have used Tortoise SVN Client for Windows and the step is from that only. It might not be available to others or may differ in existing versions**

Comment: I looked for lost changes in the log and it wasn't there.  I believe those only show previously committed changes.

Comment: Then give a try UNDO  also do not save the solution/workspace you are working, close it. Reopen and see if it works

Comment: Admit, I don't see an undo option in the context menu.  That should be under "TortoiseSVN"?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug in TortoiseSVN.  Some other members of my team have had the same issue and it seems to happen when there are network problems.